# Office Templates in CrossOver Office

Tags: wine, microsoft-office, crossover, microsoft-word, templates

I have a very specific problem.

I am a policy debater, and I'm trying to install a Word template called Verbatim

http://paperlessdebate.com/verbatim/SitePages/Home.aspx

on my Chromebook for paperless debate. I have already installed Microsoft Office using Crossover

https://www.codeweavers.com/products/crossover-linux/download

But from here I cannot install the template into MS Word. Does anyone know how to do this? I am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I cannot install the template into Microsoft Word." Are you not sure how to do it? Will the .exe file not open in Crossover? Is there an error message displayed? Please be more specific.

Comment: I have been receiving an error message whenever I try to open it saying that macros have been disabled - however I have them all enabled as well as VBA models.

Comment: Management of Windows software (even when installed in Wine) is off topic here. You should ask about it on [SU].